# cat clipboard text into a terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, clipboard

I have text in the clipboard. I want to cat it in a terminal a pipe it into another command.

The exact use case is a PEM encoded X509 certificate on a website presented as text (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...`). I want to select it, copy it, and then cat it into a terminal and pipe it OpenSSL's `x509` utility to dump the certificate.

How does one cat text on the clipboard into the terminal? (If possible, I'd like to do it with both Linux and OS X since I use both).

Comment: Since the clipboard is an OS-specific thing (well, more like GUI-specific, but still) you won’t get an universal solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OS X, `pbpaste` and `pbcopy` do what you want—pasting and copying with stdin/stdout, respectively. [Source](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/05/manipulating-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/)

For X (as in X11/Xorg), there’s `xclip`. Writing the output to stdout can be selected with the `-out` parameter. [Source](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xclip)

Answer (score 3):

With regard to xclip *use*, I have found this to be useful - found somewhere on the net.

--8<-- clipboard --

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: someapp | clipboard     # Pipe someapp's output into clipboard
#        clipboard | someapp     # Pipe clipboard's content into someapp
#

if command -v xclip 1>/dev/null; then
    if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]] ; then
        # stdin is a pipe
        # stdin -> clipboard
        xclip -i -selection clipboard
    else
        # stdin is not a pipe
        # clipboard -> stdout
        xclip -o -selection clipboard
    fi
else
    echo "Remember to install xclip"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

## If you copied data to clipboard

`xclip` can be used to print the content of clipboard to standard out, so that you can pipe and process it as  `xclip -o -selection clipboard | ...`.

OR

Save it into a variable and `echo` it.

```
cert='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...'; 
echo $cert | ...`
```

## If the data is on a file

As everybody knows `cat` do the job.
`cat /path/to/file | ...`

## If the data is on the web

`wget` can be used to cat an online file. 
Assuming it's in a text file.
`wget -O- www.site.com/path/to/file.txt  | ...`